# After update to Node 10-alpine - ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

After I updated our server node JS to Node 10-alpine version I started to get next error

> Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable.

I have to mention that with node 8-alpine this code is working (I tried with rollback)

In my code I am trying to return file from GCloud:

```
try {
        const file = await 
         gcs.bucket(`BUCKET_NAME`).file(filePath);

        if (file) {
            const results = await file.getMetadata();
            const stream = await file.createReadStream();
            return res.pipe(stream);
            else {
                return send(res, 403)
            }
        }
        else {
            return send(res, 404);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return send(res, 500);
    }
```

Is any one met such issue after upgrade to node -10 -alpine?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the error says. `res.pipe(steam)` attaches a writable stream, `stream` to the readable stream `res`. But `stream` is a stream.Readable. Use `fs.createWriteStream(...)` or `file.createWriteStream(...)` instead. This might have worked before because your `gcs.bucket(...).file(...)` function returns a file with a writable file descriptor. So it might be a case of duck typing gone wrong.